# Why the cubic formula only gives three roots

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, arithmetic, roots, radicals

When considering the formula for the solution to a degree three polynomial equation, I observe that it involves two different square roots inside of two different third roots.  From the standpoint of complex analysis, each square root represents two different possible branches, and each third root represents three different possible branches.  So in principle the cubic formula appears to give possibly $3\cdot2\cdot3\cdot2=36$ different roots.  Of course we know that a degree three polynomial equation really has only three solutions.

Without using this latter fact, working just off of the formula, is there a way to see that the set of all possible choices of the roots found in the cubic equation reduces to just three numbers?

Comment: Same goes for the quartic formula as well.  Of course the quadratic formula has only one square root, so there is no reduction, or "overlapping" which needs to be explained.

Comment: They don't: the two cube roots are not independent of each other; choosing them without regard for this will generate non-solutions of the original cubic.

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cardano_formula ... The cube roots must be chosen so $ \alpha \beta = -p/3$

Comment: Look at the derivation of that formula: $x^3+px+q=0$, $x=u+v$, that gives (via $(u+v)^3=u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v)$) $u^3+v^3+q=0$, _if_ we assume $3uv+p=0$. That's the dependency @Lord Shark the Unknown mentioned.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for explaining that.  But there is still three choices for the cube root, and two choices for the square root, giving seemingly six solutions.  Is there something in the formula which suggests the necessary redundancy?

Comment: @ProfessorVector I see now the redundancy, but there are still six solutions (given two choices for the square root and three choices for the cube root).  Is there something in the formula which suggests the necessary redundancy?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I see now.  But there are still two choices for the first square root, and three choices for the first cube root (it appears the second square root and second cube root are determined by the first using the constraint you mentioned).  That leaves an apparent six solutions.  Is there something about the formula which suggests the necessary redundancy?

Comment: $x^3+px+q$ has the $3$ solutions $x= \alpha +\beta$ where 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha =\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2} \color{blue}{+  \sqrt{ \frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}}} \\
\beta =\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2} \color{blue}{-  \sqrt{ \frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Notice that if you choose to take the negative square root then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will simply swap places ( $\alpha \longleftrightarrow \beta$) and give the same value for $x$. The other roots are obtained by choosing appropriate pairs of cube roots of unity as factors of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thank you, I understand perfectly now.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Actually the issue of changing square roots is just a tiny bit more complicated than you suggested in your last comment, since the third roots in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are different.  Thus exchanging the $+$ and $-$ in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should cycle the solutions $x$, is that right?  But that raises in interesting point, since changing the choice of square root twice will return you to the original.  Thus it appears that changing the square root exchanges two of the three solutions, but leaves the other solution unchanged.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit This suggests that for one of the solutions, both of the third roots are the same, while for the other two solutions, the two third roots are different.  Does this all seem right?  Thanks!